# Can you control the colors of a RGB LED strip with pots?

Tags: led

I'm wondering if it's possible to control the colors in a LED RGB(W) strip without a device such as arduino? Just with electric components with pots for each color? Thanks

Comment: Yes you definitely can.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to light up a normal LED with a battery and a resistor, then you can do the same for an RGB LED.

If we use Arduino as analogy, instead of the "digitalWrite(LEDpin)" for a normal LED, you use 3x "analogWrite(eachRGBpin)" where the pots do the 'work' of that code.

You'd connect the common cathode to the - of the battery, (or common anode to the +) and then each of the other LED legs, via a resistor, and in parallel, to the other end of the battery/power supply.

...

Just noticed you said "strip" - you might have to clarify what that looks like if you're not referring to a simple RGB LED with the 4 legs.